# Need to create regex pattern from user input in Python

Tags: python, regex, input, iteration, logfile

I need to parse the log file that looks like this:

```
July 31 12:54:55 mycomputername updater[93309]: WARN Please send help I am stuck inside the internet

July 31 16:07:01 mycomputername process[11843]: ERROR Process failed

July 31 16:20:37 mycomputername dhcpclient[36371]: ERROR Unable to download more RAM

July 31 16:24:34 mycomputername updater[83956]: INFO Access permitted

July 31 16:43:19 mycomputername utility[31859]: ERROR Process failed

July 31 16:43:19 mycomputername CRON[31859]: ERROR: Failed to start CRON job due to hard partying.
```

I need to create a list to store all the patterns (user input) that will be searched. This list is named error_patterns and, initially it has a pattern "error" to filter out all the ERROR logs only.

```
def error_search(log_file):
   read_line = True
   error_patterns = ["error"]

   error = input("What's the error? ").lower().split()

   for word in error:
      error_patterns.append(word)
   return error_patterns
```

If I look for the "CRON Failed to start" error (for example), the output will be:

```
['error', 'cron', 'failed', 'to', 'start']
```

Now, my goal is to parse the log file, line by line, and match all of these words. I have the following code, but I am struggling with logic.
Please, suggest the best way to do this:

```
with open(log_file, mode = 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    returned_errors = []
    if read_line == True:
        for log in f:
            for match in re.finditer(str(error_patterns), log, re.S):
                match_text = match.group()
                returned_errors.append(match_text)
                # print(match_text)
    else:
        data = f.read()
        for match in re.finditer(str(error_patterns), data, re.S):
            match_text = match.group()
            returned_errors.append(match_text)
f.close()
```

The output of my function should return ONLY the line containing the last log line, as it is the only line containing ALL the words that user inputted.

```
July 31 16:43:19 mycomputername CRON[31859]: ERROR: Failed to start CRON job due to hard partying.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try:**

```
import re
from collections import Counter

# given this list of words as input
error_patterns = ['error', 'cron', 'failed', 'to', 'start']

#OR the words with a | character into a string
searchPattern = "|".join(error_patterns)

#wrap as a non-capturing group so you have valid regex as (?:error|cron|failed|to|start)
searchPattern = r'(?i)(?:' + searchPattern + ')'  

# open file and read into lines
with open('log_file.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines() #remove newlines

# loop through each line
for line in lines:
    #split line so we are using only the message part at the end
    #this removes catching the 'CRON' from 'mycomputername CRON' in the match
    message = line.rsplit(']: ')[-1]
    #if there is something (anything) matched...
    if re.search(searchPattern, message):
        #only if each word from the error_patterns list is matched at least once
        if len(Counter(re.findall(searchPattern, message)).keys()) == len(error_patterns):
            #print the full line out
            print(line)
```

**Outputs:**

```
July 31 16:43:19 mycomputername CRON[31859]: ERROR: Failed to start CRON job due to hard partying.
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it asks for all the user input
The code provided by the tutors:
  `with open(log_file, mode='r',encoding='UTF-8') as file:
    for log in  file.readlines():
      error_patterns = ["error"]
      for i in range(len(error.split(' '))):
        error_patterns.append(r"{}".format(error.split(' ')[i].lower()))
      if all(re.search(error_pattern, log.lower()) for error_pattern in error_patterns):
        returned_errors.append(log)`

Comment: I also updated the post to include sample output for better understanding

Comment: @JuliaMartynenko I've updated the answer.  The code is commented.  Hopefully this answers a way to do it?

Comment: @JuliaMartynenko thanks, mark it as the answer and/or upvote if you're happy